# Given the following fragment of code, how many tests are required for 100% decision coverage?

Tags: manual-testing, interview, coverage, istqb, test-coverage

```
if width > length
    then
    biggest_dimension = width
    if height > width
        then
        biggest_dimension = height
    end_if
else
    biggest_dimension = length
    if height > length
        then
        biggest_dimension = height
    end_if
end_if
```

Given the following fragment of code, how many tests are required for 100% decision coverage? **According to my calculation the answer should be 6 as I am calcualting true and false for each if condition but the actual answer is 4. can someone tell me how it got as 4?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this will help you understand why the answer is 4.

**100% Decision coverage**

[image]

[image]

The code traverses 4 paths/decisions for 100% Decision coverage.

This happens when the decision statements are nested. In this case

"`height > width`" with execute only if "`width > length`" is true.

"`height > length`" with execute only if "`width > length`" is false.

Hence the minimum number of test cases required to cover 100% decision testing is 4.

---

**Edit:** As per Polina's request I'm adding explanation for **100% Statement Coverage.**

For this same piece of code you can achieve 100% Statement Coverage with just 2 sets of inputs,

Case 1.

```
Height = 10
Width = 8
Length = 5
```

In this case,

- `if width > length` will be true. Hence next statement
  `biggest_dimension = width` will be executed.
- `if height > width` will also be true. Hence next statement
  `biggest_dimension = height` will be executed.

Case 2.

```
Height = 7
Width = 5
Length = 6
```

In this case,

- `if width > length` will be false. Hence next statement `biggest_dimension = length` will be executed.
- `if height > length` will be true. Hence next statement `biggest_dimension = height` will be executed.

So you need a minimum of 2 tests for 100% Statement Coverage.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. can you please tell me what will be the statement coverage in this?

Comment: is this is the solution 2 for statement coverage?

Comment: I've added the explanation for statement coverage to the answer. If you think it's help, you can up vote the answer.